# LINQ to SQL won't accept Stored procedure

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a number of stored procedures supplied by a subcontractor. I want to call these procedures from a WCF service.  LINQ to SQL refuses to accept one of them.  The procedure in question has an unusual parameter called Attachments which doesn't seem to have a type definition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetJobCardDefect]
@SessionID uniqueidentifier,
@Longitude nvarchar(254),
@Latitude nvarchar(254),

@JobDocEntry int,
@Action nvarchar(10),               --('Add' / 'Update' / 'Delete')
@DefectLineId int,
@DefectDescription nvarchar(150),   --U_DfctDesc
@Attachments as MS_AttachmentsFiles readonly,


@ErrorID int output,
@ErrorMessage nvarchar(max) output
```

When I try to drag the procedure to the SP design surface, nothing happens. No error message, but the SP is not added. Could the Attachments parameter be causing this behavior?  Some other feature of the SP?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that a number of times. I just added them manually.

Outside Visual Studio open the dbml file in a text edit, scroll down to the bottom and see how the other procedures look. Then it should be easy to add your procedure manually.

After it is added then the code has always been correctly generated for me.

Edit: changed edmx to dbml. I know this is linq to sql, just so used to saying edmx.